# Oracle SQL - Count number of jobs per month

Tags: sql, oracle, count

I'm looking to count the total number of time a type of job (G012) has appeared each month with an status_code of '5200' in each area.

The code I have so far is:

```
select area.area_name, count(area.area_name)
from area
inner join central_site on central_site.area_code = area.area_code
inner join job on job.site_code = central_site.site_code
inner join job_type on job.job_type_key = job_type.job_type_key
inner join job_status_log on job.job_number = job_status_log.job_number
where job_type.job_type_key = 'G012' and job_status_log.status_code = '5200'
group by area.area_name
order by area.area_name
```

I'm not sure how to get this to count so that each month is in a different category - but what I would like to end up with is something like:

```
Area             April     May     June    July    August    September    October
North Ward         2        5        3       2        7         4            3
South Ward         2        3        4       4        6         4            4
```

Comment: Do you have any date column in your DB?

Comment: Have you considered pivot?

Comment: date column would come from job.actual_start_date

Comment: I'm relatively new to Oracle SQL and don't know what pivot is

Comment: Month from different years should be considered as a one group?

Comment: no it should be considered separate.  apr-19 should be separate from apr-20.  we only went live with the contract and have data from april 2019 but going forward it would be sensible to have different years as different values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you have to group the data also by the month:

```sql
select area.area_name,  EXTRACT(MONTH FROM job.actual_start_date) mon,  count(area.area_name)
from area
inner join central_site on central_site.area_code = area.area_code
inner join job on job.site_code = central_site.site_code
inner join job_type_key on job.job_type_key = job_type.job_type_key
inner join job_status_log on job.job_number = job_status_log.job_number
where job_type.job_type_key = 'G012' and job_status_log.status_code = '5200'
group by area.area_name,  EXTRACT(MONTH FROM job.actual_start_date)
order by area.area_name
```

Instead of `EXTRACT(MONTH FROM job.actual_start_date)` you could also use `TO_CHAR(job.actual_start_date, 'Month')` for the name instead of the number.

To get your desired output (month as columns instead of rows) you can use pivot:

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM (select area.area_name,  EXTRACT(MONTH FROM job.actual_start_date) mon
          from area
         inner join central_site on central_site.area_code = area.area_code
         inner join job on job.site_code = central_site.site_code
         inner join job_type_key on job.job_type_key = job_type.job_type_key
         inner join job_status_log on job.job_number = job_status_log.job_number
         where job_type.job_type_key = 'G012' and job_status_log.status_code = '5200')
PIVOT (
  COUNT(*)
  FOR mon IN (1 AS January, 2 AS February, 3 AS March, 4 AS April, 5 AS May, 6 AS June, 7 AS July, 8 AS August, 9 AS September, 10 AS October, 11 AS November, 12 AS December)
)
```

To separate the data also by year, just add a `EXTRACT(YEAR FROM job.actual_start_date)` column everywhere there is `EXTRACT(MONTH FROM job.actual_start_date)` now.

Comment: Thank you for this - but it is now giving me the error message
[Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-01722: invalid number

Comment: Hmm, basic query works for me, but i can't test with your inner select. Has to be some issue with your data i think. What datatype is `job.actual_start_date`?

Comment: job.actual_start_date is a date-time field and returns values such as 01/02/2019 12:13:34.    Was wondering if it was because it is trying to total area.area_name and this isn't a number but is text?

Comment: No it has nothing todo with area_name beeing a string. There has to be some equation comparing varchar2 against number, most likely in one of the join conditions. This is no problem as oracle performs implicit casts until a non-numerical value is fetched.

Comment: It could also be the calling point in your application. Perhaps you have defined the return values to be `varchar2, integer` and now added a new column `mon` with the name of the month as new 2nd column that will not return the integer expected but the new month-string.

Comment: Thank you - I've been through the SQL again and noticed that I've referenced the wrong field in the WHERE statement.  It should say  where  job_type.job_type_CODE = 'G012'       

Once I changed this the coding you mentioned above has worked perfectly.